# How can I put a custom drawable on the shift-state of a certain Android soft-key?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-drawable

For my Android custom soft-keyboard I have learnt how to put drawables on "normal" letter keys like this:

```
<Key android:codes="32" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_space"/>
```

Now for a minority language and a certain vowel "ɩ" (U+0269) I have the problem, that the Android system font is showing the lower case as distinct from "i" (U+0069), but the upper case keys look the same for "Ɩ" (U+0196) and "I" (U+0049). Not here in your web browser but on many Android phones. (Actually this is funny: Here where I enter this text, they look distinct, but once rendered and down in the pre-view they also look similar. Bother.)

So I want to help our users and put a drawable on the upper case key for "Ɩ" but of course there needs to be a separate one for the lower case "ɩ". Or even better, if I could leave the lower case key unaltered.

Where can I place my drawable? In the XML file for my keyboard layout there are no capitals, seems they get dynamically generated somewhere.